# Reverse Engineering poorly documented Java from source

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I'm a systems engineer, recent college grad, and I've just been given a project that is exceptionally daunting.

We have a legacy system, we legally own the entire code and all rights to it.  The problem is that the code is poorly documented, what little documentation is incomplete, sometimes wrong and the original devs are unavailable.

It uses a custom Perl build script requires a thousand modules from CPAN to work and I do not know Perl.  Reverse engineering into UML has failed except with Doxygen and that is limited to just inheritance diagrams and call graphs.

I've obtained a massive chalkboard and I'm slowly trawling through the code, modeling packages and then the nested packages within.

My question is whether or not I'm approaching this reverse engineering from the right direction. I'm working close from the bottom trying to figure out what calls what while developing UML and writing a Design Document. I did a package diagram but it's hard to figure out what's going on at that high a level.

An academic paper I pulled up suggests I also make a new Requirements Document which would slow me down even more and I don't know if it's a good idea as the other developers are always busy trying to keep the legacy system up.

Are there any books out there that can help me and am I approaching this from the right angle? Should I hire a contract worker that knows Perl and JMX to assist me?

Comment: Another tool you may find of use in undertsanding the Java code is Google's Code Analytix, which includes support for dependency analysis. http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html

Comment: If I were you, and if I had the choice, I wouldn't bother with UML at all. This is not to say that UML is bad, it's just that emphasizing on UML alone, will not get you any greater understanding of the codebase. Stick to simple class diagrams and call graphs and DFDs if you can. Your objective is to understand the codebase, not get pretty pictures of it.

Comment: @Vineet: while you're drawing diagrams to help you understand the code, you may as well make them valid UML, to ensure that they mean the same thing to everyone else as to you.

Comment: @Michael, yes that would help to some extent. But having worked on something similar, I thought I would lend my experience there. UML helps when the design is good. But when, all of the design is bad, the reverse-engineered diagrams serve little or no purpose, for the code must be refactored to make the diagrams look good.

Comment: @Vineet: I agree that reverse-engineerd diagrams are mostly useless, though I'd say the problem is that the value of diagrams is showing the important structures and leaving out the rest, which you cannot do automatically (though there can be some value in seeing which classes are depended on the most, since those are probably important).

Comment: @Michael, agreed. You might want to add the point to your answer that the diagrams ought to serve the purpose of discovering the set of core classes with the important responsibilities, so that they could be refactored first. I think I read this in Robert Martin's book, but I can't remember (may be it was Fowler).

Comment: @Vineet @Michael I've already used a diagram to isolate 4 major packages that do the heaviest lifting, but the codebase is VERY large and packages are nested very deeply. UML is used internally so it's important as many developers in the future will have to read my work.

A full system rewrite at this time is impractical and it needs to be up 24/5.

Comment: The original coders followed Object Oriented principles but have gone a bit overboard and lost control of their code very early on which is why only limited class level documentation exists for the oldest of classes.

Comment: my expertise is in Java and web dev, not Perl and especially not build automation.  Should I get someone much more experienced to help me?

Answer (score 7):

The book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers will probably help you more than anything we can tell you here.

However, the most important thing you need to clarify for yourself (and from your question it sounds like it's not completely clear) is this: what is your goal? What do you want to achieve with this codebase?

If the answer is (as it sounds) "being able to effectively maintain the existing project", then trying to directly build a complete high-level model of the system may not be the most effective path. It's probably just too much at once to keep in mind.

In this case, I would try to understand only the use cases of the system that you currently need to modify; follow method calls through the code (pssibly using a debugger on the running system) to see what parts are involved. Do this for a few different use cases and you'll start to see patterns, then document those and gradually fit them together into a high-level image of the system.

Comment: While the current goal is to clarify the code and help maintain it, ultimately it will be reengineered with proper documentation and clearer design patterns.

Comment: Regardless that book has been ordered and is enroute.

Comment: I would second Michael's comments. In practice reengineering software works best when done incrementally, and the Feathers book provides plenty of advice on techniques for introducing testing into existing applications. Constructing tests will give you a better understanding of the existing code and with luck enable you to restructure it a bit at a time.

Comment: Would like to +10 this answer. Trying to understand a large legacy app with poor docs is mainly futile. Even if you do get your head round it, the moment you work on something else and then come back to the legacy app it won't make sense again and you'll struggle to understand the documentation you wrote. I've made this mistake a couple of times in the past and learnt from it. Just try and understand small bits at a time, ie if you need to modify a feature or recreate some functionality in a new app. Consider your effort to understand these small chunks as throwaway.

Comment: @Qwerky: I wouldn't say throwaway - after a while you'll start to get an idea of the overall design, if there is one.

Comment: @Qwerky @Michael I have gotten an idea of the overall design with each module split into submodules, but once we nest about 2 in it becomes convoluted with opaquely named classes referencing mythological creatures

Comment: @sqn: That does not bode well, but once you get an idea what those classes are used for, the refactoring tools of modern Java IDEs make it easy and (unless reflection is used) safe to rename them.

Comment: @Michael good news there's reflection, why would reflection be bad?

Comment: @sqn: because when you use IDE-supported refactoring to rename a class or method, it will also change all the places where it's used regularly in the code, but usually cannot catch the places where it's used through reflection (and catching those can get arbitrarily difficult when the strings used to do so are built programmatically), so those will produce a runtime exception afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](http://www.neiljohan.com/projects/reverse/) **might** assist you.

Or if the legacy system is written poorly it could just make a huge unreadable mess, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a java code then a deep reverse engineering would be very helpful.
See a documentation at: http://www.ejb3.org/jar_file_reverse/jar_file_reverse.html